# Class number one and unitary groups

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups, class-field-theory

I've come across the claim "$ U_3(\mathbb{Q}) $ has class number $ 1 $."

I've also heard about $ U_n $, or really $ PU_n $, that "up to $ n=8 $ we can find class number $ 1 $ groups but above $ 8 $ we cannot." Apparently the impossibility for $ n > 8 $ follows from Prasad's volume formula
http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1989__69__91_0.pdf
All of this is related to "schemes of groups of class number $ 1 $."

How do you calculate the class number of a unitary group? What is the class number of a scheme of groups? Where does this bound $ n \leq 8 $ come from?

Context: These quotes are from papers and lectures by Shai Evra for example  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04710.pdf

Disclaimer: I'm very new to the concept of class number $ 1 $ and how it relates to groups so its very possible that I have incorrectly phrased a lot of these questions, but I did try to rely as much on direct quotes so things will make sense. I'm not even sure what to tag this post with because I know so little about this area.

I'm mostly looking for relevant references but I would be very interested if anyone has some thoughts or explanations about the claims above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a reductive group over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $G(\mathbb{R})$ is compact, and let $K$ be an open compact subgroup of $G(\mathbb{A}_{\mathrm{f}})$. Then the double coset space
$$G(\mathbb{Q}) \backslash \, G(\mathbb{A})\, / \left( K \cdot G(\mathbb{R})\right)$$
is finite, and its cardinality is often referred to as the *class number* of $K$. If $G$ comes with a natural $\mathbb{Z}$-scheme model $\mathcal{G}$, then the "class number of $\mathcal{G}$" is the class number of the open compact $K = \mathcal{G}(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$.

(See e.g. formula (3.8) of the arxiv preprint in your link, which states that "class number one" is equivalent to having $U_3(\mathbb{A}) = U_3(\mathbb{Q})U_3(\mathbb{R}) U_3(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$.)

As for how you compute these numbers: there is a quantity called the *mass*, which is related to the class number but is easier to work with. It's defined as the sum
$$ \sum_{g \in G(\mathbb{Q}) \backslash \, G(\mathbb{A})\, / \left( K \cdot G(\mathbb{R})\right)} \frac{1}{\#\Gamma_g},\qquad \Gamma_g = G(\mathbb{Q}) \cap g K g^{-1}.$$
There are formulae for the masses of "nice" compact opens in terms of special values of $L$-functions; and if you compute the mass of the open compact $\mathcal{G}(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ and it turns out to be equal to $1/\#\mathcal{G}(\mathbb{Z}) = 1/ \Gamma_{\mathrm{id}}$, then there can't be any more terms in the sum, so the class number must be 1. (This is pretty much what is going on from formula (3.8) to the end of the proof in the arxiv preprint.)

Comment: Specific question: in a talk by the author of this paper in the 30 seconds from 10:30-11:00 of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LY2QaK0DeDg mentions a result about $ PU_n $, that "up to $ n=8 $ we can find class number $ 1 $ groups but above $ 8 $ we cannot." Apparently the impossibility for $ n > 8 $ follows from Prasad's volume formula. He says this result is work by particular authors but he has a bit of a heavy Israeli accent so I'm not sure who the authors are, maybe "Muhammad and Gorsefedi"? Seems like this is your field, do those names ring any bells? I'm interested in that paper.

Comment: I worked briefly in this field when I was a PhD student in 2005-6. I don't claim to be up-to-date with the latest developments. I can't understand those author names in Evra's seminar either – have you considered just emailing him?

Comment: Ok your comment inspired me to be brave and email him, hopefully this works!